# Url heading when clicking links from SO post do not change when they should

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When you click a link on a SO post, the app correctly renders the webpage from a browser within the SO app. But when you navigate away from the original page you visited, the url heading does not change. It will be easier to see what's going on from the photo I've attached below. I clicked a link from a question on SO. When I clicked "powered by WordPress" in the footer, I was taken to WordPress.org, but the url heading in the SO app did not change.

[image: url]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out. We just needed to update the navigation bar's title whenever a new page is loaded.

This will be fixed in **beta version 1.1.0.132**.